# Authenticated REST API for a mobile app and website on ASP.NET Core

Tags: rest, azure, asp.net-identity

I want to build a REST API, to be hosted on Azure, built from the "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)" template stores the identities in EF.

I want to avoid having Views etc as it clutters the codebase.

It should then be callable as described in this article (TL;DR: header authentication and POST to a /token endpoint and controllers with [Authorize])
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2015/03/25/securing-and-securely-calling-web-api-and-authorize/

However, I fail to find how to get to the /token endpoint in ASP.NET Core. I'm reading a bunch of stuff on JWT, Bearer, OWin, ..., and that Basic Auth is bad, but am lost on how to proceed.

The API would be used by a website and mobile apps.

What do I need and what steps do I need to take to get a "hello world" up and running?

Also, why am I seemingly the only one with this architecture?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a *token endpoint* in ASP.NET Core.

You can build a custom middleware, as explained in this article: [ASP.NET Core Token Authentication Guide](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core)
Or you can use an external package:

- [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4)
- [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server)
- [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core)

For the last, I suggest this article: [Bearer Token Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/27/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/)

If you are interested in an Angular 2 SPA with ASP.NET Core Web API that uses token authentication (through IdentityServer4), give a look at this repository: https://github.com/robisim74/Angular2SPAWebAPI (disclaimer, it's mine).

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer, but can you dumb it down for me? I have started an empty project, added the code snippets from here https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server to my project. I can request a bearer token (POST to /connect/token). To GET, I set the Authorization header with the token but I keep on getting a 401 Unauthorized. What other code do I need to add?

Comment: @WouterVanRanst have you added the OAuth2 validation middleware in your pipeline? If it's there and if you're still seeing an error, please consider opening a new SO question with some code ;)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516170/authenticated-rest-api-for-a-mobile-app-and-website-on-asp-net-core-with-openidc for the follow up question with more details on OpenIdConnect